# How to make a proper xpath a profile on instagram?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, instagram

I keep getting this error. I want to select one user then scroll down from the list but I get the error "no such element: Unable to locate element:" even though I checked and there is such an element with this xpath. https://www.instagram.com/leomessi/followers/ I want to select one of the followers.
So I would like to extract the username which is the red rectangle. Then I would like to check the name in green rectangle if it matches certain conditions. After that I want to click on Follow and scroll down to next user which i tried with `self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", current_user)`
https://prnt.sc/i-6easCn1E3W
So the major problem is that Im not sure if I should use  the xpath and how to specify that or any other css selector?

```
    def follow_followers(self):
        user = input("account username: \t")
        self.go_to_user(user)
        temp = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a/span/span").text
        num_of_followers = self.convert_to_number(temp)
        amount = random.randint(20, 50)
        temp = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[2]/a").click()
        i, k = 1, 1
        while(k <= amount):
            waiting_time = 3600/50
            self.wait(1,3)
            current_user = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='mount_0_0_iW']/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[{}]/div".format(i))
            button = current_user.find_elements(By.XPATH, ".//button")
            name = current_user.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[11]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/a/div/div/span").text
            if button and button[0].text == "Follow":
                self.wait(waiting_time-10,waiting_time)
                button[0].click()
                self.add_followed_list(name)
                k+=1
            self.wait(1,2)
            self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", current_user)
            i += 1
```

I tried to take xpath and full xpath for different div's and still i got this error. The error is with

```
current_user = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='mount_0_0_iW']/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[{}]/div".format(i))
```

Comment: Please share the URL/HTML

Comment: @MendelG added the URL

Comment: @Madiuso Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The `{}` in `div[{}]` are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct, and needed button is Follow Buttons on modal, correct selector is

`[role=dialog] ._aano button`

and name element is corresponding by index and selector

`[role=dialog] .x1q0g3np a span`

so name and button

```py
dialog = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[role=dialog]')

name = dialog.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '._aano button')[i].text
button = dialog.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.x1q0g3np a span')[i]
```

And in this case you don't need to check button text for clicking on it.

Using `non-relative selector` is bad practice as far as you rely on each level DOM structure that can be easily changed.
You should use `relative` selectors if you want your tests to be broken rarely than once per day.

[image]

Comment: How should I find proper selector for the name as u did? So basically in button I should do just 'button.click()' as it is the follow button?

Comment: Yes. 
Well, you should search for unique and stable attributes. Instagram hiding original class names (or generate auto class names) to avoid bots are scrapping. But it still has unique attributes. 
Example - root of your dialog has unique attribute `[role=dialog]`. So you can rely on it (like usually on roles, when you don't have id / classes / hooks, etc.)

Comment: Then you searching for another `stable` level until you get your button. I found one element with class `._aano`, that points to button. (It has only needed button inside)

Comment: So, we getting 3 level selector (which is a lot, but in this case they seemed not to be changed) that points us to needed button. Same logic for nickname.